# How to click-through on transparent parts of cocoa web view

Tags: cocoa, webview, mouseevent, transparent, click-through

Okay so I have a web view that holds the chat bar div from Facebook.com. 
The web view itself is larger/taller than the bar because obviously it needs to be for when a chat box is opened. 
When a chat box isn't open though, that area of the web view is transparent. 
I need the transparent areas of the web view to ignore mouse events and send them to whatever is behind.

How should I go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subclass the WebView and implement your own `hitTest:` method.

Comment: This did it for me, with a static IB label on top of an NSView instance. I'm implementing a Photoshop-like panel of "layer" rows, each displaying a label with the layer name (the name is not editable in-place, though). I want to show a context menu (right-click), to edit, delete, etc. but the text label was getting in the way. Thanks!